How can chain Monos while preserving some original value(s)?
I have the following four methods.
Mono<A>   tearUp(   );
Mono<B>      doB(A a);
Mono<C>      doC(B b);
Mono<D> shutDown(A a);

A simplest workflow would be look like this.
tearUp()
    .flatMap(a -> shutDown(a))
    .block();

Now how can I call above four methods in a row?
I know I can do this.
A a =   tearUp( ).block();
B b =      doB(a).block();
C c =      doC(b).block();
D d = shutDown(a).block();

How can I nicely use the Mono while invoking tearUp, doB, doC, and shutDown?
I tried with this. Is this right?
tearUp()
    .flatMap(a -> doB(a).flatMap(b -> doC(b)).thenReturn(a))
    .flatMap(a -> shutDown(a))
    .block();


yes, you can do that

For your specific use-case that seems to be opening/closing a resource, you can also use Mono.usingWhen : Mono<C> result = Mono.usingWhen(Mono.defer(() -> tearUp()), a -> doB(a).flatMap(b -> doC(b)), a -> shutdown(a)). You can check an example in this answer.

you can use thenReturn doc to preserve your expect data
like following code snippet

tearUp()
    .flatMap(a -> doB(a)
        .flatMap(b -> doC(b)
            .thenReturn(a))) // Preserve 'a' before proceeding to shutDown
    .flatMap(a -> shutDown(a))
    .block();


